# What is the definition for "Peace of Mind"?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

The definition for "Peace of Mind" has always been somehow unclear to me.
Is there even a clear definition for it? Or is it just subjective?

Answer (score 1):

The ancient Greeks called pure and robust peace of mind Ataraxia.  It is when one discovers no belief can ever be justified, at least according to the Pyrrhonists. As such, one suspends judgement upon anything non-evident.  The condition was said to have fallen upon the master painter Apelles; while trying to paint the foam of a horse, likely frothy saliva near its mouth.  He was so unsuccessful, in despair, he threw the sponge he was using to clean his brushes with at the medium and created the effect of the horse's foam.  Both the Stoics and the Epicureans also made use of the term.